# Subquery must return a single row

Tags: sql, cloudera, impala

When I start this query I got this error:

> AnalysisException: Subquery must return a single row: `(SELECT round(c1.feb15 + c1.nov15 + c1.dec15) FROM suivisousse.compteur2015)`

Query:

```
SELECT
    c2.compteur, 
    ((c1.feb15 + c1.nov15 + c1.dec15) * 100 / 
         (SELECT ROUND(c1.feb15 + c1.nov15 + c1.dec15) FROM compteur2015)) 
FROM
    compteur2015 c1, compteur c2 
WHERE
    c1.compteur = c2.compteur
GROUP BY
    c2.compteur
```

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: I've looked at this a few times and cant work out what exactly you are trying to do. Get the percentage relative to an average in some way, but not sure how. Clearly your subquery is returning more than 1 row, so you need to correlate it to the main query. I think because your average is c1.columns and your from is compteur2015. Try restructuring your query using `join on` syntax to make it more readable.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably trying to write this:

```
SELECT c2.compteur, 
       ( SUM(c1.feb15 + c1.nov15 + c1.dec15) * 100 / 
         (SELECT SUM(c1.feb15 + c1.nov15 + c1.dec15) FROM compteur2015)
       ) 
FROM compteur2015 c1 JOIN
     compteur c2 
     ON c1.compteur = c2.compteur
GROUP BY c2.compteur;
```

However, this is more simply written as:

```
SELECT c2.compteur, 
       ( SUM(c1.feb15 + c1.nov15 + c1.dec15) * 100 / 
         SUM(SUM(c1.feb15 + c1.nov15 + c1.dec15)) OVER ()
       ) 
FROM compteur2015 c1 JOIN
     compteur c2 
     ON c1.compteur = c2.compteur
GROUP BY c2.compteur;
```

Comment: the first one returns an error : AnalysisException: Subqueries are not supported in the select list. 
but the second one worked perfectly and for that thank you my friend! but can you tell me why the 1st one returned error ?

Answer (score 0):

Your inner select query `select round(c1.feb15+c1.nov15+c1.dec15) from compteur2015` returning more than 1 record. Make sure there is only one valid record returned by your inner query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select c2.compteur, ((c1.feb15+c1.nov15+c1.dec15)*100 / (select round(c1.feb15+c1.nov15+c1.dec15) from compteur2015 c15 where c1.compteur = c15.compteur )) 
from compteur2015 c1, compteur c2 
group by c2.compteur
```

Comment: i wanted to calculat percent of traffic in feb, nov and dec 2015. 
and btw it didnt work either :/ still the same problem 
* im workin with impala

Comment: do you want to calculate percentage of feb,nov and dec on bases of these 3 months e.g 100% =  fed%+nov%+dec%?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you’re trying to achieve. You don’t seem to need the subquery.

Try this:

```
SELECT
    c2.compteur, 
    (c1.feb15 + c1.nov15 + c1.dec15) * 100 / ROUND(c1.feb15 + c1.nov15 + c1.dec15)
FROM compteur2015 c1
    INNER JOIN compteur c2 
        ON c1.compteur = c2.compteur
GROUP BY
    c2.compteur
```